# All future HTTP requests break, if internet goes down once

Tags: javascript, web-services, qt, xmlhttprequest, qml

I am calling some HTTP GET/POST methods using qml/Javascript. In general they look as follows :

```
    function someWebServiceGETCall()
    {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var url  = "http://someUrl/webServicePoint"

    http.open("GET", url, true);

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    http.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if( XMLHttpRequest.DONE === http.readyState )
        {
            if(  http.status == 200 )
            {
                // All good, got response
            }

            else
            {
                if(0 === http.status)
                {
                    // Server down !?
                }

                else if(  400 == http.status )
                {
                    // Server returned some sort of error
                }
                else
                {
                    // Some error, I have no clue why!
                }
            }
        }
    }

    http.send();
}
```

All the functions work fine other than this peculiar issue :

1. My application is running and am calling some services, things work fine.
2. Assume user is not using the app for a while and in between internet goes off. Now, even if the internet is back, I keep getting into this condition :

   ```
   if(0 === http.status)
   {
       // Server down !?
   }
   ```

Whatever happens in the system now, all the GET/POST ends up in this condition. I have to restart the app, and then everything starts working.

Is there some sort of initial handshake on internet availability which is not getting refreshed ? Do I need to manually check for internet availability ?

And ideas what can I do to avoid this ?

---

**Edit : I have added the standalone code to replicate.**

Run the app, click on screen, response comes and is shown on screen.

With app still running, shut down the internet.

Switch on the internet.

Now click on the screen again to send the request. It should say 'server down!' now on all subsequent clicks.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window
{
visible: true
width: 500
height: 500

function someWebServiceGETCall()
{

 busy.running = true

 var http = new XMLHttpRequest()
 var url  = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"

 http.open("GET", url, true);

 http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

 http.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
     if( XMLHttpRequest.DONE === http.readyState )
     {
         busy.running = false

         if(  http.status == 200 )
         {
             responseText.text = "All good, got response"
             print ("All good, got response")
         }

         else
         {
             if(0 === http.status)
             {
                 responseText.text = "Server down !?"
                 print ("Server down !?")
             }

             else if(  400 == http.status )
             {
                 // Server returned some sort of error
             }
             else
             {
                 // Some error, I have no clue why!
             }
         }
     }
 }

    http.send();
}

MouseArea
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: someWebServiceGETCall()
}

Text
{
    text: qsTr("Click to Call the service")
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}

Text
{
    id: responseText
    text: qsTr("")
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
}

BusyIndicator
{
    id: busy
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    running: false
}
}
```

---

**Edit 2 :**

Reported as a bug here : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52197

Comment: Sounds strange. I've take out my Internet cord and then returned it back. And so I've tested the code before and after that. It works good in both attempts. Did you try to run some another app when Internet back?

Comment: @folibis Yes, other apps work fine. Infact, if I restart my app, it works fine as well. Can you try stopping the internet while a request is in progress and check if subsequent ones work for you later on ?

Comment: @folibis I have added a stand alone piece of code, can you try replicating it ?